# override for custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that I use like this:

```
AppTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AppTableCell" owner:self options:nil];  
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[AppTableCell class]]) {
            cell = (AppTableCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Works flawlessly. But, I would like to do some custom things to the cell when they get created. Normally I would override something like `initWithFrame`, but its not being used here. What method should I override to customize initialization?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The right way is to override awakeFromNib for UITableViewCell.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Do something
}
```

See [references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Objects that are unarchived from a nib are sent the `-initWithCoder:` message. That's your override point.

Comment: If object use outlets or actions it not works because its are not connected